# Refactor Automation Framework To Work With Multi Browsers

Tags: c#, selenium, automation, webdriver, automated-tests

Posting here as my googling and searching stackoverflow hasn't given me quite what I am looking for. So, hopefully someone here can point me in the right direction or give me some pointers on how to solve my issue.

Preface: I have been teaching myself C#/.net for a little over a year now and still consider myself a novice. But in that time I have gone from a manual software tester to getting myself my first job as an Automation Engineer.

I've currently built a framework using Selenium Webdriver and the page object model framework. And the issue I have is currently my framework ideally only allows for one browser at a time. I could have different browsers being used at the same time, but i'd have to have the multiple versions of the test too.

Below is an example of how my framework is currently. As I'd imagine this would help.

```
public class WebDriver
{
  public static IwebDriver driver;
}
```

Then this is inherited by my TestBase class, which is attached to each test

```
public class TestBase: WebDriver
{
    public TestContext TestContext { get; set; }

    [TestInitialize]
    public void Initialize()
    {
        Driver = new ChromeDriver();
    }

    [TestCleanup]
    public void Cleanup()
    {
        //Company specific cleanup logic
        //Reporting Etc. 
        Driver.Quit();
    }
}
```

This base class is then inherited by each test class; seen below.

```
[TestClass]
public class LoginTests : TestBase
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void SuccessfulLogin()
    {
        LoginPage login = new LoginPage();
        login.NavigateToLogInPage();
        HomePage homePage = login.LoginWithCorrectDetails();
        homePage.LogoutFromHomePage();
    }
}
```

What I was planning on doing was having a "Testbase" class for each browser (Chrome, firefox, IE) and would then have a version of each test, that would inherent a browser.

So, in the example below there would be

> SuccessfulLogin: Chrome
>
> SuccessfulLogin: FireFox
>
> SuccessfulLogin: IE

While this would would, (I did a short test), it's far from ideal and I can imagine will cause various issues later on down the line.

What I'm looking for is help/direction in which I only have one version of my test and my framework is intelligent enough to run it on all browsers.